# Derivatives of Schwarz functions at $x=0$.

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

**Problem:** Given an arbitrary sequence $a_n$ of positive numbers, is it possible to find some Schwarz function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that 
$$|f^{(n)}(0)| \geq a_n \, \forall n ?$$

If not, how fast can $b_n=f^{(n)}(0)$ grow?

**Note:** It is clear that the above is not true for analytic functions. But it is not clear to me if it could actually hold for Schwarz functions.

Comment: [Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) lets you do just that. You can always multiply by smooth cut off function later. A nice proof of the special case of the lemma can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Application_to_Taylor_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  r9m said the best answer is Borel's lemma saying the map sending smooth functions to their formal Taylor series at $0$ is surjective.

> Otherwise there is a non-constructive proof

If there exists $(b_n)$ such that for all Schwartz function $f^{(n)}(0)/b_n \to 0$ let $$g_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{|b_{2n}| 2^n} \delta^{(2n)}(x)$$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle g_n,\phi\rangle$$ converges for all Schwartz function $\phi$, it means so does $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle g_n,\hat{\phi}\rangle=\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle \hat{g_n},\phi\rangle=\langle \hat{g_\infty},\phi\rangle$$

Where
$$\hat{g_\infty}(\xi)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|b_{2n}|2^n} (2\pi \xi)^{2n}$$ 
It is obviously wrong because $\hat{g_\infty}$ grows faster than polynomials so that $\frac1{1+\hat{g_\infty}}$ is Schwartz and clearly $$\langle \frac1{1+\hat{g_\infty}},\hat{g_\infty}\rangle= \infty$$

Comment: (+1) Nice argument!